# How to reorganize the data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with 400000 rows. The data consists of 3 columns date, stock name, stock price. The csv file has data for over 50 stocks for the past 15 years. I have used data frame for reading the data from csv file. The dataframe is similar to the df1 as given below.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3'], list('AAABBBCCC'), [1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3,3.1,3.2,3.3]]).T
df1.columns = ['dt','stockname','price']
print(df1)
```

I want stock names as header and dates as index. How to convert or organize the csv to represent a dataframe as similar to the df2 given below.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['d1','d2','d3'],[1.1,1.2,1.3],[2.1,2.2,2.3],[3.1,3.2,3.3]]).T
df2.columns=['dt','A','B','C']
df2.set_index('dt')
print(df2)
```

Comment: Do you have duplicates in your columns `(d1, d2)` in your real dataframe? Try to check `df1.value_counts(['col1', 'col2'])`

Comment: all columns have duplicate values

Comment: So `pivot` can't work, you have to use `pivot_table`. Suppose you have two identical rows like `(d1, A)` with value 4 and 2. What do you want to do? take the mean (3), the first value (4), the last value (2), the max (4), the min (2) or apply a custom function?

Comment: I have updated the question to imply more information

Comment: So there is no duplicate records for a same (datetime, stock), isn't it?

Comment: yes for given datetime, and stock there wont be any duplicate

Comment: Ok. so you can use my code below. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot`:

```
>>> df1.pivot('dt', 'stockname', 'price').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()

   dt    A    B    C
0  d1  1.1  2.1  3.1
1  d2  1.2  2.2  3.2
2  d3  1.3  2.3  3.3
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: It didn't solve my problem. I am getting the error-'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'.

Comment: So you have multiple records for a same `(dt, stockname)`...